# C# Crc32 implementation

Tags: c#, cryptography, mifare, crc32, desfire

I´ve got the following example:

```
3D020000000F0000112233445566778899AABBCCDDEEFF - Crc32 Input
280ACDA5 - Crc32 Result
```

But with the following Calculators: [sunshine2k](http://www.sunshine2k.de/coding/javascript/crc/crc_js.html) and [zorc.breitbandkatze](http://www.zorc.breitbandkatze.de/crc.html) I can´t reconstruct the result. The documentation says: Polynomial-`04C11DB7`, Reverse-`EDB88320`, Initvalue-`FFFFFFFF` and also the Result should not be reversed.

I´ve searched for libraries on NuGet and found [Nito](https://nugetmusthaves.com/Package/Nito.HashAlgorithms.CRC) but do not get the right result either. I´ve also tried every combination with flags and polynomials (`04C11DB7`, `EDB88320`).

Can someone tell what I´m doing wrong? Are the calculators and the lib wrong? Also I´ve tried same combination of polinom and flags on both sides and the lib but got different result :-( may someone tell a lib which is definatly reight?

Here my Testcode:

```
        [Theory]
        [InlineData("3D 00 00 00 00 10 00 00 23 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 12 34 56 78 00 00 00 00", "7B 8A 60 0F")]
        [InlineData("3D020000000F0000112233445566778899AABBCCDDEEFF", "280ACDA5")]
        public void Crc32_Test(string input, string assumedCrc32)
        {
            var definition = new Definition
            {
                Initializer = 0xFFFFFFFF,
                TruncatedPolynomial = 0xEDB88320,
                ReverseResultBeforeFinalXor = false,
                ReverseDataBytes = false,
            };

            var whow = new Nito.HashAlgorithms.CRC32(definition);

            var inputArray = DESFireSessionHandler.StringToByte(input);
            var assumedCrc32Array = DESFireSessionHandler.StringToByte(assumedCrc32);

            var crc32 = whow.ComputeHash(inputArray);

            if (crc32.SequenceEqual(assumedCrc32Array))
                Assert.True(true);
            else if (crc32.Reverse().SequenceEqual(assumedCrc32Array))
                Assert.True(true);
            else Assert.False(true);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following parameters produce the desired result 280ACDA5:

```cs
Initializer = 0xFFFFFFFF,
TruncatedPolynomial = 0x04C11DB7,
FinalXorValue = 0x00000000,
ReverseResultBeforeFinalXor = true,
ReverseDataBytes = true
```

---

This is identical (except for the order of the bytes) to the online tools:

https://crccalc.com/

[image]

http://www.sunshine2k.de/coding/javascript/crc/crc_js.html

[image]

---

The complete C# code is:

```cs
using System;
using static Nito.HashAlgorithms.CRC32;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var definition = new Definition
        {
            Initializer = 0xFFFFFFFF,
            TruncatedPolynomial = 0x04C11DB7,
            FinalXorValue = 0x00000000,
            ReverseResultBeforeFinalXor = true,
            ReverseDataBytes = true
        };

        var inputHex = "3D020000000F0000112233445566778899AABBCCDDEEFF";
        var input = Convert.FromHexString(inputHex);
        var whow = new Nito.HashAlgorithms.CRC32(definition);
        
        var crc32 = whow.ComputeHash(input);
        var crc32Hex = Convert.ToHexString(crc32);
        Console.WriteLine(crc32Hex); // 280ACDA5
    }
}
```

Comment: That you very very much :-)